# Would I reverse this calculation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which works out margin price etc.

I'm wondering if I can reverse my Margin Calculator?

Presently it works out the Margin %

```
=((I1-F1)-H1-K1-N1)/I1
```

(I=Net Price, F=Cost, H=Carriage, K=Fees, N=Promotions)

I want to be able to type a Margin % and it calculates the price and if possible add the round up feature? so everything ends in .99.

Using

```
=ROUNDUP(SUM(I864*M864)+(I864),0.1)-0.01
```

(M being Margin field) it calculate using the margin, but it differs from the original price

e.g. Price 69.99=19% Margin
Reverse Calculation 19%=66.99

Difference of 3, i'm really confused and cannot get my head around this, can someone please shed some light?

Comment: The forward calculation results in 19%. You need to divide by 119% to achieve the original value. This is a fairly typical before-tax, after-tax calculation.

Comment: I think it would help you to solve this on paper before you formulize it.

Comment: btw, your [ROUNDUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDUP-function-F8BC9B23-E795-47DB-8703-DB171D0C42A7)  function will likely come back to byita. Currency is generally calculated to a minimum of **4* decimals while displaying 2 (or other) on the worksheet.

Comment: If `M1 = ((I1-F1)-H1-K1-N1)/I1` then reverse `I1 = (F1+H1+K1+N1)/(1-M1)`.

Comment: AxelRichter Fantastic, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If `M1 = ((I1-F1)-H1-K1-N1)/I1` then reverse `I1 = (F1+H1+K1+N1)/(1-M1)`.

This is done using math to change the subject of the formula:

```
M1 = ((I1-F1)-H1-K1-N1)/I1                    / parenthesis not necessary

M1 = (I1-F1-H1-K1-N1)/I1                      / multiply out brackets (*1/I1)

M1 = I1/I1 -F1/I1-H1/I1-K1/I1-N1/I1           

M1 = 1 -F1/I1-H1/I1-K1/I1-N1/I1               / -1

M1-1 = -F1/I1-H1/I1-K1/I1-N1/I1               / *I1

(M1-1) * I1 = -F1-H1-K1-N1                    / *-1

-1*(M1-1) * I1 = -1*(-F1-H1-K1-N1)            

(1-M1) * I1 = F1+H1+K1+N1                     / /(1-M1)

I1 = (F1+H1+K1+N1)/(1-M1)
```